# Does someone knows why url: 'data.html' in Request.HTML won't work on some webhosts (when data.php does)

Tags: mootools

I had to work with a new webhost and I noticed that my regular Mootools 1.3 Request.HTML, ie:

```
var makeRequest = new Request.HTML({
             method: 'get',
             url: 'data.html',
//etc
```

would not work, when it would work with data.php,

or :

```
var myrequest = $(dorequest).get('href');
                 var myReq = new Request.HTML({
url: myrequest,
 method: 'get',
```

with the following html :

```
<a href="testlink.html" class="makeRequest" >Get HTML</a>
```

**Settings** :

PHP 5.2 through an htaccess

Mootools 1.3.2

I guess it is related to the web server settings, but I am not so sure.

Could someone suggest an explanation ?

Comment: What do you mean by "would not work"?

Comment: The HTML page called doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Things you can do:

- Register event handlers for the "failure" and "exception" events of the Request object and check the event arguments for more information about the error that might have occurred.
- Compare the headers of the HTTP request and response for the both files (*.php and *.html). They might be different, causing the server to return two different responses.
- Provide us with the complete code, the snippets posted are not complete.

Comment: I think the answer is very simple.                                     Some webhosts have strict policies concerning XMLHttpRequest. Some even block all XHR. My webhost must have a middle-ground policy.